# Stub! at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:14) in android testing

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

im trying to do a unit test for a class that contains this method:

```
private void launchIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShareLocationActivity.class);
        ((ChatActivity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, ShareLocationActivity.SEND_LOCATION_REQUEST);
    }
```

When the test try to do new Intent i get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:14)
```

Im doing this to mock my needed context activity

```
@Mock
private BaseActivity activity;
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if you still need the answer than i've found it!
You need to **sync gradle files**
Use Ctrl + Shift + A to search and search for "Sync Project with Gradle Files".
Hope it helps.